# How to select the text in the address bar while browsing Google search results in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I don't know why Safari 7 doesn't allow me to select the text in the address bar in one step while browsing google search results.

In other sites I just have to click once on the address bar and that's it, the whole text is selected.

Google search results instead makes Safari to put the caret in the address bar but won't select the text, also double-clicking (or clicking N times) won't select the text either, what I have to do is click once, wait and triple-click to select the whole text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the favicon in the address bar (small image at left-hand side). This will select the entire URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>.

Comment: That's a lowercase `L`.